# jQuery slider breaks if user clicks next before it can hide the button

Tags: jquery

**Before I start, I am well aware of all the different Slideshow plugins available for jQuery but I have chosen to build a custom version myself for various reasons.** So please don't link to plugins etc as I have seen them all before and don't wish to use them.

The following slideshow DEMO >> http://jsfiddle.net/mm7sx/

Everything works fine apart from if a user clicks the next button too fast and they get to the last div in the slideshow they can call the next div (which doesn't exist) before the next button can disappear.

Any ideas on how to fix this? I'm not sure what the exact problem is, but I'm guessing that the problem is related to me NOT checking if a next div exists before trying to load the next div... Does anyone have any suggestions? Ideas for improvements to get around this issue?

I've tried doing an if statement checking if the length of next is greater than zero or not but that didn't fix the problem either.

Thanks

Comment: ok check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/rfUyn/

Answer (score 0):

You animation is queueing, you can use jQuery's [stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method to stop the currently running animation.

EDIT::

It looks like your next button hides based on the `:visibile`ity of your last slide, try hiding the button when you click it, before the slide animates, by checking if there is a next slide instead.

Comment: Are you sure that's the problem? Could you perhaps update my fiddle to demonstrate the fix as I'm not sure where abouts the animation is quing up to break it like it is doing. Cheers

Comment: Tried that too but still breaks if the user clicks the next button quick enough.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the checkButtons() call should be the first thing inside the $('li.next a').click(function () {});

```
$('li.next a').click(function () {
    checkButtons();

    //rest of the code
});
```

Also

```
var dot = $(this);

var target = $(dot).attr('href'); //use dot without the $ wrapper
var target = dot.attr('href');    //dot already cached
```

**EDIT**

OK, I got it working:

http://jsfiddle.net/rfUyn/

Comment: OK then. Maybe you could try to pass an argument e.g. currentSlide to the checkButtons function and if you also have an e.g. slidesCount variable, and make your ifs based on comparing these variables instead of the is(':visible') calls

Comment: Any chance you could edit the fiddle with an example as I have no idea what you mean I'm afraid.

Comment: I can still break it if I click the next button quick enough!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by checking the length of the next element and returning false so the user could not load an non-existant div.

e.g.

```
if (!next.length) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        // Fade out the currently shown slide and fade in the next slide upon fadeout
                        shown.fadeOut('fast', function () {
                            next.fadeIn('fast', function () { checkButtons(); });
                        });
                    }
```